# Component state and hooks not updated after browser previous button visit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When doing a `window.location.href` (when submitSuccess is true) and navigate back with the browser previous button, my component does not re-render. So the `submitSuccess` and `submitting` state variables are still on `true`, while I need them to be `false` again when revisiting the application without a refresh of the page.

```
const MultipleStepForm = () => {

   const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);
   const [submitSuccess, setSubmitSuccess] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log("Running!");
   },[]);

   useEffect(() => {
      successFunction();
   }, [submitSuccess]);

   const successFunction = () => {
      window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/other-page/";
   };

   return (
      <div>
         {(submitting) && (
            <div>Submitting the form..</div>
         ) || (
            <div><!-- Form elements in here --></div>
         )}
      </div>
   );

});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `successFunction` using `window.location` the URL is redirected to your webpage too or another domain? Why it's important, React is a single page application(SPA) so if you wanna change a page in the same domain or webpage I recommend you use a router, React has `react-router` or react-router-dom.

[React Router Dom](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: It is the same domain, but the react application is only a part of the domain. So the rest is PHP. The next page isn't a react-based page, so I do not know if it is possible to use react router for this then..

Comment: Nice, maybe you could resolve with a useEffect watching your URL like this...

`
const MY_PAGE_URL = "https://www.example.com/"

`useEffect(() => {
    if(window.location.href === MY_PAGE_URL) {
        setSubmitting(false)
        setSubmitSuccess(false)
    }
},[window.location.href]);`

Comment: No but the thing is that I cannot set these variables to false when revisiting the page.. That is the reason I posted this question.